# Struts2 static content giving 404

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

1. I have apache and configured as follows:

   `RewriteEngine On
   ProxyPass / http://demo1.example.com:8080/myApp
   ProxyPassReverse / ....(same url as above)`
2. Following is the web.xml:

   ```
   <filter>
     <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
     <filter- class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>  
   <filter>
      <filter-name>UrlFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.rts.utils.UrlFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>UrlFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>     
   <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```
3. I have customised filter that reads subdoman from the url and sets in the request:

   ```
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request; 
    if(httpReq.getServerName() != null && httpReq.getServerName().indexOf(".") != -1) {
         request.setAttribute("subdomain",...);
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
     }
     }
   ```
4. I am using struts 2.3.8, Tomcat 6 & JDK 1.6. I deployed my application under webapps/myApp.

When I login into the application I can see 404 for below urls and my page is not loading properly:

```
http://example.com/myApp/struts/js/base/jquery-1.8.3.js
```

If I try the above url(directly in the browser) without giving "myApp", like below I am getting the script

```
http://example.com/struts/js/base/jquery-1.8.3.js
```

This means struts2 is not generating the static content in right contextpath?

Comment: do you have any other filter ? can you copy relevant parts of your code?

Comment: @yeppe Thanks for your reply.. Yes I have another customized filter to read subdomain name. Following is the code for that:                                                                                                                  `<filter>
 <filter-name>UrlFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>com.rts.utils.UrlFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
</code>
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>UrlFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>`

Comment: edit your question and put the relevant code from web.xml/App/ etc.

Comment: What do you mean by *generating the static content in right contextpath*?

Comment: What is your urlfilter doing? Do you have some http server in front of your app server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the solution to this problem..I just wanted to post here, that may help someone.

`<sj:head />` does the trick, this is the tag helps to copy the static content from jar files.

If we deploy the application as ROOT, we just need to add `<sj:head/>`, this will copy the content to `<context>/struts/...`

If we deploy myApp to webapps, `<sj:head/>` copies the content to /myApp, but the framework search for "/struts/.." that will not be aviable.

Solution: `<sj:head>` tag has the attribute "scriptPath", this tells to frame work where to copy the content. I added below code in my jsp fixed the issue:

`<sj:head compressed="false" scriptPath="/struts/"/>`